# how to rewrite a IF loop statment into openyxl iteration loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, openpyxl

I have written this code using a for loop to get data from excel and write back to excel (it didn't work). I was able to save only the last row data. Other data are not saved.

I got to know about iteration method in openpyxl, but didn't got enough resource to learn it.

Could anyone tell me how to rewrite the below for loop into openpyxl iteration?

```
import openpyxl

for i in range(2,4):

wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('comp.xlsx')
sheet=wb.get_sheet_by_name('comp')
url=sheet.cell(i,2)
print(url.value)

r=requests.get(url.value)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")

g_data = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"search-page-heading-red"})
for cname in g_data:
    com=sheet.cell(i,5)
    com.value = cname.text
    print(com.value)
    wb.save('compfinal.xlsx')
```

Comment: You're not increasing the row number. Use `enumerate`

Comment: In the above example I used the for loop and increased the row number. Can you show me any example increase the row number using enumerate.

Comment: I see no incrementing. `enumerate()` is built into Python.